# How can I remove the word "tabs" at the beginning of the tabbar in airline-vim?

Tags: plugin-airline, original-vim

I would like the tabbar to start with the first tab not with "tabs".

```
"tabs>1 main.tex>2 section_01.tex>     <tab 2/2"
```

Comment: please show a screenshot? is this vim-airline plugin?

Comment: Ah, yeah you are right it is probably from the plugin - using it for so long that I didn't even notice myself.

Comment: please read the plugins documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help I forgot about airline, airline#extensions#tabline#tabs_label = ''" solves it - should I remove the question?

Comment: no, rather answer it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The actual behavior occurs because of the vim-airline plugin and can be removed adding the following property to your vimrc:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tabs_label = ''
```

So there will be no more leading "tabs>" in the tabline.

Comment: This doesn't really look like valid vimrc syntax... Are you missing a `let` command there perhaps? If so, I'd call that a "variable" rather than a "property" since that's the usual naming for `let`. Is it a global variable and, if such, should you be explicit and use a `g:` prefix to make that clear? (Not sure how the plugin documentation examples are written... Probably best to keep consistent with them.) Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden indeed, in the doc it is like this: `* rename label for tabs (default: 'tabs') (c) >
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tabs_label = 't'`

Comment: you are totally right - wasn't on stackexchange since then -> so I missed it - sorry